# Controller for HDMI to 30-pin display connector converter

Tags: pcb, lcd, display, adapter, hdmi

I need to design a circuit for HDMI to a 30-pin eDP adapter. Do I need to use some high-speed microcontroller that takes the signal from HDMI or forwards it to the eDP connector or is there some chip available which does the same. I tried to search on the internet for some open source project of the same sort but I could not find one. So, it would be great if someone points me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll most likely want to find an off the shelf chip for this. This is not possible to do with a microcontroller, and doing it with an FPGA is likely possible, but extremely expensive.